# Pause a timer in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a small generic 4 stage pipeline and it simulates for the clock period provided. However i wanted to pause it and resume it in the middle and am not able to do that. This is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5q02vrnt/) and for the pause i thought of adding a flag.

```
if flag == 1 //keep simulating
if flag == 0 // pause simulation where it is
if flag == 0 and click resume resume simulation until its end

var flag = 1; //initial value
function pause(){
 flag = 0;
}
function resume(){
 flag = 1;
}
//i try to check if flag is 0 then alert pause or something but no luck

function startSim(){
  document.getElementById('clockDiv').innerHTML = 'Clock Period '+clockPeriod;
  if(index == 22){
    clearInterval(sim);
  }else if(flag == 0){
      alert("Simulation Paused");
  }else{
  clockPeriod++;
    fetch();
    decode();
    execute();
    store();
  index++;
 }
}
```

I would appreciate tips on how to do this.

Comment: add your code to the question, and not just as a link, also, if you just want to pause it, then check if your flag differs from 0 before you do any calculations, if not, do nothing until flag gets changed again

Comment: @Icepickle sorry i have added my code now. I am not sure what you meant I am doing what you are saying

Comment: Your problem here is actually how your code is loaded. If you check the console output, you will see clicking on pause throws an error that it doesn't find the method "pause", so your flag doesn't get set to 0. Add it to the header rather than use the onload function of jsfiddle. You can do it by clicking the javascript settings wheel, and then choosing wrap in body or wrap in head (default is onload)

Comment: I am very curious who is the so very active downvoter in this topic...

Comment: Why is everything downvoted? How was this question even bad? It's not like i asked someone to do my homework lol ?

Comment: I am guessing people want to get some hatz and you get them for voting today...

Comment: I was wondering the downvoting thing as well... shame :|

Comment: wtf is happening in this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not so much your code, but rather how the default way of loading javascript in jsfiddle is working (nl, onload, so an anonymous function)

Therefor your functions pause / resume are no longer available when you click your buttons.

To change this, you can change the way the javascript is loaded inside your page, for you the easiest is:

[image]

At this time your code will partly work (alert is very annoying as it pops up at every interval), and your reset won't work because the `var sim` was defined locally (as @razzak mentioned in another answer)

Comment: yes that works, is this only a jsfiddle issue? if i add this code to my actually js on my pc things should work fine?

Comment: @user1010101 pretty much yeah, it's just something you need to know

Comment: @user1010101 btw, the other answers are all very good suggestions to improve your code, but only razzak actually found out why it is ;)

Comment: @Icepickle but question not only about fiddle, it also about the code improvements. I agree, all suggestions good

Comment: @ioganegambaputifonguser It seems he wanted to know why his code wasn't working, and it was a wrong setup, it is true lots of improvements can be suggested, but I didn't see this as part of the question

Comment: @Icepickle I have interpreted this one `I would appreciate tips on how to do this.` Tips or improvements. The fiddle just a place for code demonstration. And anyway I did not down vote you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should change the JavaScript settings in Fiddler: set "Load Type" to no-wrap and your code will work.

Although I would suggest using clearTimeout instead of flags.

Answer (score 1):

I think thats not just a fiddle issue, look at this:

```
function start(){
var sim = setInterval(function(){startSim()},500);
}

....
if(index == 22){
  clearInterval(sim);
}else if(flag == 0){
  alert("Simulation Paused");
....
```

you re creating sim inside the local scope of the function and then using it inside an other function... this is actually an error.

use this:

```
function start(){
    return setInterval(function(){startSim()},500);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/95fy5tw9/)

Answer (score 0):

If a user click pause, you setup the flag and handle it in the `startSim` callback. If `flag == 0` you try to simulate pause, but your index counter becomes 22 at 11 secs. It will be clear very fast, before you click pause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my go: http://jsfiddle.net/j82j14r6/2/

Instead of `setInterval`, I am using `setTimeout` and having a function call itself:

```
function tick()
{
   if(!paused)
   {
         // Do stuff
       document.querySelector('#log').value = ticks;
       ticks++;
   }

   setTimeout(tick, 500);
}
```

This allows for easy control over tickrate, pausing, ending, etc.

Please note that using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is not exactly the most accurate way to calculate time and / or make loops like this, but in case your project is not too important - this is a ok way to do it.

As to why your buttons are not calling the corresponding functions... that is mostly a jsfiddle problem. I fixed this with `addEventListener` in the JS section, instead of having `onclick` on the HTML button itself.

```
<input type = "button" value = "togglepause" id = "pausebutton"/><br/>

document.querySelector('#pausebutton').addEventListener('click', togglepause);
```